# How can i use an Interceptor to set a field in Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, interceptor

i have a controller like following

```
@RestController
class TestController{
 private String country;

  public String m1(){}
  public String m2(){}
  public String m3(){}
  public String m4(){}

}
```

All the methods m1 to m4 needs the country that is taken from the header.

is there a method to do that for all the methods of this controller.

I tried using Interceptor but, i am not able to get country after the interceptor execution is over. that is i always get country a null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring MVC provides [`@RequestHeader`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestHeader.html) which

> indicates that a method parameter should be bound to a web request header

Annotate your handler method parameter appropriately

```
@RequestMapping("/somePath")
public ReturnType example(@RequestHeader("country-header") String country) {
    // use it
}
```

The Spring MVC stack will extract the header value and use it to invoke your handler method.

Comment: thanks for the answer. but i was just curios, if there is a way to do the same for all the requests to this controller. just like Grails provide a beforeInterceptor.

Comment: @EkanshRastogi I don't know Grails. Unless otherwise specified, `@Controller` beans are singletons. You wouldn't set the header value to an instance field because you'd risk thread safety issues. The Spring MVC way to therefore get the value is to get it through a handler method parameter.